# correct work with onActivityResult in MVP project

Tags: android, onactivityresult, android-mvp

I try use MVP in my project and I get some question.

For example I have

```
MyPresenter presenter;
MyFragment view;
```

In view I have `button` with name "open barcode scan" witch is open barcode scan activity like this:

```
IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan()
```

Hwo must cal this code? `view` or `presenter`?

1 View realization:

```
scanButton.setOnClickListener(view -> IntentIntegrator.forSupportFragment(this).initiateScan());
```

2 presenter realization:

```
scanButton.setOnClickListener(view -> presenter.openScan());
```

And next question - How must process `onActivityResult`? and How?

for example

```
@Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
 switch(requestCode){
  case 
  ...
  case 
  ...
  case 
//it is logic
}
```

EDIT

1 way

```
@Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     switch(requestCode){
      case 
      presenter.callMethod1()
      case 
      presenter.callMethod2()
      case 
    //it is logic
    }
```

2 way

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
         presenter.onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Presenter` acts as the bridge or the middle man between `View` and `Model`, so **it must be called on the View**.

`onActivityResult` will be as is on your `fragment`. and then, if you need to save the result from the scan, that's the time you need to call the `presenter`.

> A presenter typically hosts business logic associated with a particular feature, and the corresponding view handles the Android UI work. The view contains almost no logic; it converts the presenter's commands to UI actions, and listens for user actions, which are then passed to the presenter.

*Reference: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/*

You might be mistaken the `onActivityResult` is where the business logic is, **it is not**. That's why you need to pass it to the `presenter` when you get the result so the presenter will process (business logic) it and then give it to your repository that will save it.

Comment: yes, I do about all the same. The question is also about what exactly to transfer to the presenter from onActivityResult?  If I pass 3 params int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data presenter will be know about Intent    class(android.content) but I think presenter do not must know about android framework classes. And if I process data in fragment - it means that I implement logic.

Comment: Processing requestCode, resultCode does not count as logic because you're just going to get the actual data to pass it on the presenter.

Comment: this code in onActivityResult  is good way?
       String[] cardData = result.getContents().split(" ");
        presenter.makePay(cardData, basketAdapter.getData());

Comment: I guess you should pass the `result.getContents()`  and then split it on the `presenter`.

Comment: @ip696 I wonder what you ended up doing regarding the question of `onActivityResult()`?